# Is it possible to bulk load an NDB child Entity in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

At some point in the future I may need to bulk load migration data (i.e. from a CSV).  Has anyone had exceptions raised doing the following?  Also is there any change in behaviour if the ndb.put_multi() function is used?

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

while True:

    if not id:
        break
    id, name = read_csv_row(readline())
    x = X(parent=ndb.Key('Y','static_id')
    x.id, x.name = id, name
    x.put()

class X(ndb.Model):

    id = StringProperty()
    name = StringProperty()

class Y(ndb.Model):

    pass

def read_csv_row(line):

    """returns tuple"""
```

Comment: Yes, but the code you have supplied won't work.  If you run that code you will get lots of exceptions ;-).  Things to think about if the whole process takes longer than 60 seconds use a task. If you need to user a task, then upload the file first to GCS, then fire off a task to do the import.

Comment: @TimHoffman, thanks for the advice.  I'll look into using GCS.  The actual code is for inbound mail that may come in at >1 message per second for a short time, thus requiring some queuing I'm guessing. Any idea how I'd go about that?

Comment: You could store the emails in the datastore, or gcs if they are bugger than 1MB. Keep a proxy object in the datastore. Then you can use those records as your queue.  Fire off a named task to process all mail in the queue or as much as you can in 10min. It's worth having a read of some of Nick Johnson's articles on task queues - http://blog.notdot.net/tag/deferred . In fact I would suggest it's worth reading all of his articles on appengine ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research and thanks to comments it seems that the code above (where it made into valid code) create problems which would eventually lead to google.appengine.api.datastore_errors.Timeout exceptions being thrown.

See another question:

[Datastore write limit tests - trying to break app engine, but it won´t break ;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339395/datastore-write-limit-tests-trying-to-break-app-engine-but-it-wont-break)

The best suggestion I have so far is to use a Task Queue to to rate limit this.  More information on:

blog.notdot.net/tag/deferred